# Is there a way to automate creation of sharepoint online connection in logic app using ARM template?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to automate creation of sharepoint online connection in logic app using ARM template? I am trying to create ARM template for my logic app for CI/CD pipeline. My logic app has a sharepoint trigger. In the portal, it takes single sign-on to connect to sharepoint. How to automate this using ARM template?

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I think that you may have to configure your SSO with Azure using Azure AD Connect. Once that is done, you can then create an API connection against it in your Logic App using ARM. Here's the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#connection-resource-definitions

Comment: No, I didn't find a way to automate it using ARM templates. We have opted to manually open and authorize the connection post deployment.